# How can I validate a file type using Nestjs Pipes and FileTypeValidator

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have implemented a simple Nestjs route inside of an controller with a file upload. The file is handled with [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). Since its porpuse is to edit a profile picture of a user I need to validate the file to be an image. However for some reason I can't get it running with the `FileTypeValidator`. The uploaded file is being denied each time.

```
@UseInterceptors(
  FileInterceptor('file', {
    storage: MulterService.getStorage((req, file, cb) => {
      const filename = `${uuidv4()}`;
      const extension = path.parse(file.originalname).ext;

      cb(null, `${filename}${extension}`);
    }, MulterService.destinations.profilePictures),
  })
)
@Post('profile-picture')
editProfilePicture(
  @UploadedFile(
    new ParseFilePipe({
      validators: [new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: 'png' })],
      // png files always denied
      // /\^(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$/ regex isn't working either
    })
  )
  file: Express.Multer.File
): Promise<User> {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If this`/\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/` will not work use this`'.(png|jpeg|jpg)'`

```
@UploadedFile(
    new ParseFilePipe({
      validators: [
        new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: max size of file in bytes }),
        new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: '.(png|jpeg|jpg)' }),
      ],
    }),
  )
  file: Express.Multer.File
```

Comment: Code-only answers should be updated to explain how the code resolves the question, further guidance can be found in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I tested your regex pattern and it seems not matching with image extensions you provided and instead it assumes there will always be dot character at beginning. so what I did was I removed the first two character `\.` from regex and it works. Here's the final regex: `(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)$`

**Edit**
You can validate it through ParseFilePipe or ParseFilePipeBuilder validation Pipeline
**ParseFilePipe**

```
@UploadedFile(
    new ParseFilePipe({
      validators: [
        new MaxFileSizeValidator({ maxSize: max size of file in bytes }),
        new FileTypeValidator({ fileType: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/ }),
      ],
    }),
  )
  file: Express.Multer.File
```

**ParseFilePipeBuilder**

```
@UploadedFile(
    new ParseFilePipeBuilder()
      .addFileTypeValidator({
        fileType: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/,
      })
      .addMaxSizeValidator({
        maxSize: max size of file in bytes
      })
      .build({
        // Custome Message???
        errorHttpStatusCode: HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
      }),
  )
  file: Express.Multer.File
```

Comment: I tried using the above pattern and I'm getting error:  Validation failed (expected type is /\\.(jpg|jpeg|png)$/)",